# When using natbib, references do not appear

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm new in latex world and I'm having troubles using natbib package.
I have used this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} 
\begin{document} 

blabla \citep{prova1}

\medskip 
\begin{thebibliography}  
\bibliography{prova1}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I get no errors but the .pdf file has a (?) instead of the author and in the references there's only written the key, which I use to cite, just as if it is text. I guess the problem is in the .bib file that I got automatically with Mendeley software. The "prova1.bib" file is the following:

```
@ARTICLE {prova1,
    author  = "pincopallino",
    title   = "prova",
    journal = "test",
    year    = "2014"   
}
```

I apologize if my explanation is unclear, any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please indicate whether you wish to generate authoryear-style or numeric-style citation call-outs (the output of `\cite`).

Comment: remove the \begin{thebibliography}   \end{thebibliography} , they are generated automatically.

Comment: Hello @Mico, thank you for your help. I would like to use an authoryear-style citation in my thesis.

Comment: @user225946 - Since you use the `abbrvnat` bibliography style, it should suffice to change `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` and to run a full recompilation cycle (Latex, BibTeX, and Latex twice more) in order to get authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use both `\begin{bibliopraphy}` and `\end{bibliography}` as well as `\bibliography` at the same time
- Use `\begin{bibliopraphy}` and `\end{bibliography}` only if you desire to build the entire formatted bibliography by hand.
- If you use `\bibliography`, you must also use BibTeX (an external program) to create the formatted bibliography.

If you want to use BibTeX, you should rewrite the code posted above as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
% create the file 'prova.bib' on the fly:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{prova.bib}
@ARTICLE {prova1,
    author  = "pincopallino",
    title   = "prova",
    journal = "test",
    year    = "2014"   
} 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} 

\begin{document} 
blabla \citep{prova1}
\bibliography{prova}  
\end{document}
```

and then run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to (a) create the formatted bibliography and (b) all the citation call-outs.

Comment: Excuse me @Mico, I don't understand what does it mean to "run BibTex". I created the .bib file from a software called Mendeley Desktop.

Comment: @user225946 - Please tell me which front-end software you employ to edit and compile your tex files.